# Network related and instanceerror?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have deployed my desktop application on clients machine , I used SQL Server an C#.The problem is that when i run my application on clients machine and i click on any button it gives me error attached in the image [image]

Can anyone explain me why i am having this problem .Any help would be very helpful ??
I am using a default instance and my connection string is :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CS"
     connectionString="Data Source=HOMESWEETHOME;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=TRUE"
     providerName ="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: have you tried googling that error ?

Comment: Either your client can't resolve the server name or your SQL server doesn't allow external connections.

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

1. If your client machine can ping the SQL Server machine.
2. If your SQL Server allows remote connections. You might need to open up Port 1433.

doesn't look like an authentication error. (yet)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your SQL Server Service is running (usually named 'Sql Server (INSTANCE NAME)' in your services list.

If connecting to a remote DB,  check if remote connections are enabled:

Depends on the version of SQL Server you are using:

**SQL 2005**

1. Start -> Programs -> Sql Server 2005 -> Configuration Tools -> Surface Area Configuration
2. Follow the instructions in this article:  [[HERE]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178763%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

**SQL 2008 and above**

Follow the instructions [HERE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) to allow remote connections and configure TCP/IP and other protocols